How to style dayHeaders and dayGrids in FullCalendar in Vue?
I'm new to Vue and JS in general, currently trying to implement a calendar using FullCalendar. I would like to change the text color of the day headers and days but unable to do so. I read the documentation where there is an option for Day-Header Render Hooks but I've tried and it didn't work, the following are my code:
<template>
    <FullCalendar class="calendar-app-calendar" :options="calendarOptions">
        <template v-slot:eventContent="arg">
            <p> Text </p>
        </template>
    </FullCalendar>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
    import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
    import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

    const handleDayHeader = (arg) => {
        arg.el.style.color = 'red';
    }

    const calendarOptions = ref({
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth' //,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        dayHeaderDidMount: handleDayHeader,
        dayHeaderClassNames: (arg) => {
            console.log('dayheaderclassnames...', arg);
            return ['week-header'];
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .week-header {
        color: red !important; /* Change text color of weekend headers */
    }
</style>


I tried the code I provided above but it did not have any effect on my calendar. I expect the text color of day header "Mon, Tues etc." to change to red.

Based on the documentation, one of the ways you can use (and that you have also used in your code) is dayHeaderDidMount - called right after the <th> has been added to the DOM.
const handleDayHeader = (arg) => {   arg.el.style.color = 'blue'; }

This line here changes the color of text inside <th> element, which in this case is 'blue' (and red in your code).

So, your code should look like this:
<template>
    <FullCalendar class="calendar-app-calendar" :options="calendarOptions">
        <template v-slot:eventContent="arg">
            <p> Text </p>
        </template>
    </FullCalendar>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
    import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
    import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

    const handleDayHeader = (arg) => {
        arg.el.style.color = 'red';
    }

    const calendarOptions = ref({
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth' //,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        dayHeaderDidMount: handleDayHeader
    });
</script>

And the result:

Hope this will helps!!!

Thank you for your reply, sadly I'm still yet to see a change in color for my day headers despite using the same code above, do you know what might caused this?

That's weird, maybe a reason can be having other CSS styles that are overriding this. Try to inspect the headers (right click - inspect)  and see if the red color appears in the styling or not. Try to change it from the inspect tab to see if it works. If not then maybe you will need to check for other stylings that are affecting your headers.
